# Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"sf", "CRS"’

Tags: r, gis

this fullcode of R how to export the result to shp file?

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
library(raster)
library(ForestTools)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(dplyr)
library(lidR)
library(sf)
setwd("D:/LAPTOP AA/76_E_D")
stackData <- stack("76_E_Double_transparent_mosaic_group1.tif_AOI.tif")
brickData <-brick(stackData)
red = brickData[[1]]
green = brickData[[2]]
blue = brickData[[3]]
ratioGreen = green/(red + green + blue)
writeRaster(x = ratioGreen,
            filename="ratioGreen76D.tif",
            format = "GTiff", # save as a tif
            # datatype='INT2S', # save as a INTEGER rather than a float
            overwrite = TRUE)  # OPTIONAL - be careful. This will OVERWRITE previous files.
### Tree top
# chm = raster('CHM_res.tif')
chm = raster('D:/LAPTOP AA/76_E_D/New folder/CHM_DSMAGS_DTMADJ_AOI.tif')
# lin <- function(x){x * 0.05 + 0.6}
# lin2 <- function(x){x * 0.07 + 0.9}
# ttops <- vwf(CHM = chm, winFun = lin, minHeight = 5)
ttops <- tree_detection(chm, lmf(ws = 3.5, hmin = 5, shape="circular"))
extractValue <- extract(ratioGreen, ttops)
extractValue[is.na(extractValue)]<-0
ttops$veg <-extractValue
result<-ttops[ttops$veg > 0.37,]
plot(result)
# Export
proj4string(result) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32748")
writeOGR(result, dsn = "result.shp", layer = "result", driver = "ESRI Shapefile" )
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

and this line always show error

```
proj4string(result) <- CRS("+init=epsg:32748")
    writeOGR(result, dsn = "result.shp", layer = "result", driver = "ESRI Shapefile")
```

and this is error message

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘proj4string<-’ for signature ‘"sf", "CRS"’ and
Error in writeOGR(result, dsn = "result.shp",layer = "result", driver = "ESRI shapefile") :
inherits(obj, "Spatial") is not TRUE

how to fix this error? please help me

Comment: `sf::st_crs(result) <-  32748`, but it is unclear if you have an `sf` to assign to yet, as `inherits(obj, 'Spatial') is not TRUE)` ... class(ttops) might clarify at `ttops<-ttops[ttops$veg > 0.37,]` so we can separate from 'result'. Then `sf::st_write`

Comment: can u write thefullcode

Comment: It is just a sanity check question, what is the class of result at your `result<-ttops[ttops$veg > 0.37,]`. It should still be `sf` as that is what `locate_trees(` is supposed to return, but I don't have the data, so I ask what is `class(` at that point in your code? which as your 'result' or my 'ttiops' should be `sf` but you have the data so I don't know. Thereafter, we should check the 'crs' of 'ttops'/'result' to see if it is the same as rasters or needs to be transformed...then use `sf::st_write(` instead of `writeOGR(`, but will only know if we know the class, so what is class(?

Comment: i mean tree_detection not locate_trees